# How Exactly Does Ansible Parse Boolean Variables?

Tags: boolean, ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

In Ansible, there are several places where variables can be defined: in the inventory, in a playbook, in variable files, etc. Can anyone explain the following observations that I have made?

1. When defining a Boolean variable in an inventory, it MUST be capitalized (i.e., True/False), otherwise  (i.e., true/false) it will not be interpreted as a Boolean but as a String.
2. In any of the YAML formatted files (playbooks, roles, etc.) both True/False and true/false are interpreted as Booleans.

For example, I defined two variables in an inventory:

```
abc=false
xyz=False
```

And when debugging the type of these variables inside a role...

```
- debug:
    msg: "abc={{ abc | type_debug }}  xyz={{ xyz | type_debug }}"
```

... then `abc` becomes `unicode` but `xyz` is interpreted as a `bool`:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "abc=unicode  xyz=bool"
}
```

However, when defining the same variables in a playbook, like this:

```
  vars:
    abc: false
    xyz: False
```

... then both variables are recognized as `bool`.

I had to realize this the hard way after executing a playbook on production, running something that should not have run because of a variable set to 'false' instead of 'False' in an inventory. Thus, I'd really like to find a clear answer about how Ansible understands Booleans and how it depends on where/how the variable is defined. Should I simply always use capitalized True/False to be on the safe side? Is it valid to say that booleans in YAML files (with format `key: value`) are case-insensitive, while in properties files (with format `key=value`) they are case-sensitive? Any deeper insights would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

## Variables defined in YAML files (playbooks, vars_files, YAML-format inventories)

---

### YAML principles

Playbooks, vars_files, and [inventory files written in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41094864/2947502) are processed by a YAML parser first. It allows several aliases for values which will be stored as `Boolean` type: `yes`/`no`, `true`/`false`, `on`/`off`, defined in several cases: `true`/`True`/`TRUE` (thus they are not truly case-insensitive).

[YAML definition](http://yaml.org/type/bool.html) specifies possible values as:

> ```
> y|Y|yes|Yes|YES|n|N|no|No|NO
> |true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE
> |on|On|ON|off|Off|OFF
> ```

[Ansible docs confirm that](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics):

> You can also specify a boolean value (true/false) in several forms:
>
> ```
> create_key: yes
> needs_agent: no
> knows_oop: True
> likes_emacs: TRUE
> uses_cvs: false
> ```

**However**, [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) now also states:

> Use lowercase ‘true’ or ‘false’ for boolean values in dictionaries if you want to be compatible with default yamllint options.

So keep that in mind if you use tools like `ansible-lint`, that will not be happy by default (`Truthy value should be one of [false, true]`)

---

---

## Variables defined in INI-format inventory files

---

### Python principles

When Ansible reads an INI-format inventory, it processes the variables [using Python built-in types](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/inventory/ini.html#synopsis):

> Values passed in using the `key=value` syntax are interpreted as Python literal structure (strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, None), alternatively as string. For example `var=FALSE` would create a string equal to `FALSE`.

If the value specified matches string `True` or `False` (starting with a capital letter) the type is set to Boolean, otherwise it is treated as string (unless it matches another type).

---

---

## Variables defined through `--extra_vars` CLI parameter

---

### All strings

All variables passed as extra-vars in CLI are of string type. You can work around that by using JSON syntax. Example:

```
--extra-vars '{"abc": false}'
```

`abc` will then be of type `bool`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It really helped a lot. But still it lead me to yet another confusion: [What causes Ansible to evaluate 'false and true' as 'true'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881789)

Comment: great answer and this explains what to do to force variables as boolean anyways: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37895365/1904815 (use the `bool` filter)

Comment: You can also [pass variables as json](https://drewbuntu.com/2018/10/19/ansible-footnote-passing-a-bool-with-extra-vars/) to force them to be interpreted as booleans without needing to change your playbooks.

Comment: While true, extra-vars in Tower/AWX jobs are not from the CLI; they really are YAML (well, the YAML ones are) and thus are subject to the same parsing/processing as other YAML vars. So for booleans, not all extra-vars are strings. Only the CLI ones.

Comment: Beware: `ansible-lint` now warn you if you use something else than `yes` or `no`: `Truthy value should be one of [false, true]`

Comment: I added an example on how to pass boolean values via `--extra-vars`. Feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Answer (score 1):

The YAML principles define the possible Boolean values that are accepted by Ansible. However after parsing only two values remain (true and false), these are valid in JSON too, so if you do some things with these values **in** Ansible, then **true** and **false** are good choices. Also the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) states

> Use lowercase ‘true’ or ‘false’ for boolean values in dictionaries if
> you want to be compatible with default yamllint options.

```yaml
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---

- name: true or false?
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: "all these boolean inputs evaluate to 'true'"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - true
        - True
        - TRUE
        - yes
        - Yes
        - YES
        - on
        - On
        - ON

    - name: "all these boolean inputs evaluate to 'false'"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - false
        - False
        - FALSE
        - no
        - No
        - NO
        - off
        - Off
        - OFF
```