# Prevent conversion of variable to bool in Ansible

Tags: ansible

How to run a task conditionally when the user provides some input to `vars_prompt`.  Problem is, my variable is treated as bool and `yes` and `no` are never matched.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "myvar"
      prompt: "Do you want to proceed(yes/no)?"
      private: no

  tasks:

    - name: "Set variable"
      set_fact:
        myvar: "{{ myvar }}"

    - name: "Conditional task"
      shell: echo "conditional action"
      when: "'yes' in myvar"
```

I am getting following error message when I run above code:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}
```

MSG:

```
The conditional check ''yes' in myvar' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if 'yes' in myvar %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

The error appears to have been in '/home/monk/samples/user.yml': line 14, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: "Conditional task"
      ^ here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *Prevent conversion of variable to bool in ansible.*

A: See [How Exactly Does Ansible Parse Boolean Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877464/how-exactly-does-ansible-parse-boolean-variables). It's possible to simply evaluate the variable *`myvar`* in the condition

```
- name: "Set variable"
  set_fact:
    myvar: "{{ myvar }}"
- name: "Conditional task"
  shell: echo "conditional action"
  when: myvar
```

The condition *`when: "'yes' in myvar"`* does not work because *`myvar`* isn't a list. This the reason for the error:

> argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

---

Notes

- Quoting from [Prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html#prompts):

> Prompts for individual vars_prompt variables will be skipped for any variable that is already defined through the command line --extra-vars option ...

- Quoting from [Passing Variables On The Command Line](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line):

> Values passed in using the key=value syntax are interpreted as strings. Use the JSON format if you need to pass in anything that shouldn’t be a string (Booleans, integers, floats, lists etc).

Therefore, to be on the safe side, use explicit *`bool`* cast

```
when: myvar|bool
```

Answer (score 3):

The conversion to Boolean is actually done when you re-affect your variable with `set_fact` which is not needed (unless you want to use it in a subsequent play). The following actually works as you expect:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    - name: myvar
      prompt: "yes or no?"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: yes was entered
      when: "'yes' in myvar"
```

**Meanwhile, this is probably not the best way to solve your problem**. I would rather cast the answer to bool to test directly on it (and you could eventually use `set_fact` again if you need you prompt in the next play).

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    - name: myvar
      prompt: "yes or no?"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: yes was entered
      when: myvar | bool
```

Comment: I want to use in multiple plays

Comment: @monk: then use the second solution as suggested which will work in either cases. This is actually what Vladimir Botka suggested in his answer as well.