# The "bool" filter in Ansible doesn't output true for non-empty strings

Tags: redis, ansible

I have this task, that executes a command & searches for `cluster_known_nodes:` which after this word, there is always a number (starting from 0):

```yaml
- name: Get cluster info from one of the nodes
  command: >
    redis-cli --user default -h {{ hostvars[groups['masters'][0]].ansible_host }}
    CLUSTER INFO
  register: cluster_info_output
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Set fact indicating if the cluster is already created
  set_fact:
    cluster_created: "{{ cluster_info_output.stdout | regex_search('cluster_known_nodes:[1-9]+') }}"
```

What I want to do, is check if that variable (`cluster_known_nodes`) is NOT `0` (any other number is acceptable for me), and if it is NOT 0 (for example 3), set the "cluster_created" fact to true.

The debug task to evaluate the `cluster_created` fact:

```yaml
- name: debug cluster_created
  debug:
    var: cluster_created | bool
```

The result:

```json
TASK [redis.cluster : Set fact indicating if the cluster is already created] ****************************************************
ok: [server1 -> localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "cluster_created": "**cluster_known_nodes:3**"
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [redis.cluster : debug cluster_created] ************************************************************************************
ok: [server1 -> localhost] => {
    "cluster_created | bool": **false**
}
```

Why is it **`false`**?

I want it to be **`true`** in this case, `cluster_known_nodes` is `3` , so it should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***The `bool` filter in Ansible doesn't output `true` for non-empty strings***

Right, that's the expected behavior. It is not a test for empty strings. See [How exactly does Ansible parse boolean variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877502/6771046) and [`bool` filter – cast into a boolean](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/bool_filter.html).

> ***Why is it `false`?***

According [`ansible/plugins/filter/core.py` - `to_bool`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L81) will cast everything to `False` which is not in

```python
    if isinstance(a, string_types):
        a = a.lower()
    if a in ('yes', 'on', '1', 'true', 1):
        return True
    return False
```

So in your case, `3` will become `False` and since [the task should run only `when` is `True`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when) you'll need to negate (`not`).

> ***I want it to be `true` in the case `cluster_known_nodes` is `3`***

You could name your variable just `cluster_nodes` and the condition `when: not cluster_nodes | bool`.

An other approach could be to cast to `int` and compare the value

```yaml
when: cluster_created | int > 0
```

or

```yaml
when: cluster_created | int != 0
```

---

To get familiar with the conditions and tests have also a look into the minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    intZERO: 0
    intONE: 1
    strZERO: '0'
    strONE: '1'

    intTHREE: 3
    strTHREE: '3'
    intEMPTY:
    strEMPTY: ''

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: |
        "{{ intZERO | bool }}"
        "{{ intONE | bool }}"
        "{{ strZERO | bool }}"
        "{{ strONE | bool }}"
        "{{ intTHREE | bool }}"
        "{{ strTHREE | bool }}"
        "{{ intEMPTY | bool }}"
        "{{ strEMPTY | bool }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    "False"
    "True"
    "False"
    "True"
    "False"
    "False"
    ""
    "False"
```