# Ansible prompt - Conditional OR

Tags: ansible

I have a OR condition in my when statment depending on the user's input.
However It'll always enter the `debug` task with my OR condition. If I remove one of the statements and type in that character, it'll skip it. As desired.

```
   - pause:
        prompt: "Please confirm? (yes|y|n)"
        echo: true
      register: confirm

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ confirm.user_input | lower }}"
      when: confirm.user_input | lower != 'y' or confirm.user_input | lower != 'yes'
```

I've tried adding parentheses around my statment to 'isolate' it, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
when: confirm.user_input | lower != 'y' or confirm.user_input | lower != 'yes'
```

This condition will be **true** in many cases because if the user enters 'y', the second part of the condition `(confirm.user_input | lower != 'yes')` is **true**. Similarly, if the user enters '**yes**', the first part of the condition `(confirm.user_input | lower != 'y')` is **true**.

I think you want to use the **and** instead of **or**

```
when: confirm.user_input | lower != 'y' and confirm.user_input | lower != 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you try to achieve it might be possible to simplify the case more. See in example a minimal playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - pause:
      prompt: "Continue? Type YES|Yes|yes|True|true|On|on|1"
      echo: true
    register: confirm

  - meta: end_play
    when: not confirm.user_input | bool

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ confirm.user_input | bool }}"
```

which test for `true` only.

**Background Information**

- [The `bool` filter in Ansible doesn't output true for non-empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77815622/6771046)