# What causes Ansible to evaluate 'false and true' as 'true'?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

Learning from a great answer to my question about [how Ansible parses Booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877464/how-exactly-does-ansible-parse-boolean-variables), I still don't understand why Ansible ends up evaluating the following condition as `True` instead of `False`:

Define two variables in an INI-format inventory:

```
a=false     # parsed as 'unicode' (String)
b=True      # parsed as 'bool'
```

Now testing some simple conditions:

```
- debug:
    msg: "The variable 'a' is true!"
  when: a

- debug:
    msg: "The variable 'b' is true!"
  when: b

- debug:
    msg: "The variables 'a' and 'b' are both true!"
  when: a and b
```

The result is that `a` is false, `b` is true, and interestingly `a and b` is also *true*!

```
TASK [jenkins : debug] **********************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => {
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", "skipped": true
}

TASK [jenkins : debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "The variable 'b' is true!"
}

TASK [jenkins : debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "The variables 'a' and 'b' are both true!"
}
```

In an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888760/ansible-when-variable-true-not-behaving-as-expected) the following is explained:

> In python any non-empty string should be truthy. But when directly
>   used in a condition it evaluates to false.

So this explains that `when: a` evaluates to False, but it does not explain why `when: a and b` evaluates to True.

It would be great if anybody could explain this outcome in detail.

Comment: I don't guess the explanation there will satisfy you, but no matter how to look at it, it is a dup.

Comment: You are right... it boils down to the same question. But you have to agree, mine is much clearer and to the point ;-)

Comment: Now I don't think that other answer is correct.

Comment: But it really helps to write `when: a|bool and b`, then the task gets `skipped` as expected.

Comment: I know the answer... but it's super-boring - let's see if it gets reopened :)

Comment: Great! Is it possible to pre-accept your future answer? ;-)